# Why doesn't Backup Manager finish my backup?

Tags: java, android, backup-agent

```
    public class MyBackupAgent extends BackupAgentHelper {
        static final String DB_FILE_NAME = "name";
        static final String DB_BACKUP_KEY = "key";

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            FileBackupHelper dbs = new FileBackupHelper(this, getFilesPath());
            addHelper(DB_BACKUP_KEY, dbs);
        }

        private String getFilesPath() {
            File path = getDatabasePath(DB_FILE_NAME);
            return path.getAbsolutePath();
        }
}
```

The reported output is:

```
04-27 21:54:13.681: V/BackupManagerService(1087): addPackageParticipantsLocked: #1
04-27 21:54:13.681: I/BackupManagerService(1087): Scheduling backup for new app my.package
04-27 21:54:13.681: D/BackupManagerService(1087): Now staging backup of my.package
04-27 21:55:11.621: D/BackupManagerService(1087): couldn't find params for token 0
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that there is a problem in the first place? Those logs really don't look like they are supposed to indicate any kind of error.

Comment: there is no backup when i change the device, the last line of log appears to indicate some problem

Comment: I doubt it. Do you see the the `D/` right after the date and time? That indicates a debug log entry. It isn't supposed to indicate an error at all.